# Delphi web browser component as DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, chromium-embedded, twebbrowser, cef4delphi

I'm relatively new to Delphi, in an internship role. A few weeks ago I was asked to create a proof of concept for using a very basic web browser that gets called from a DLL, and then the browser would navigate to a specific website. My proof of concept needs to implement a DLL based on the requirements of the main application. The components I've been asked to research are TWebBrowser, [DCEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3), and [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi).

Over the last number of weeks I've noticed different issues with each component which I'll speak about briefly to try and give an overview.

TWebBrowser:
I understand that TWebBrowser is essentially Internet Explorer, specifically the version of IE that resides on the machine. And I understand about setting the document mode in the registry, as it defaults to IE7 mode unless set. I've noticed that even setting the document mode to the highest that this component has issues with some JavaScript and rendering. There's a specific part of the website that it needs to interact with that displays selectable images. When I visit this site in any IE11 it interacts fine, but through the TWebBrowser component the images display but can't be selected. I've not been able to find anyone who has experienced the same issue, so I've moved away from TWebBrowser.

DCEF3:
This was very promising. I was able to make a standalone browser that interacted perfectly with the website. There were no issues until I attempted to move this into a DLL. All goes well until the web browser form is freed; the application hangs and becomes unresponsive. The only way I can get it to not hang is to remove the FreeLibrary() method. The problem with that is then I have an orphaned process that is still running after the call application has finally closed down. Windows 10 deals with that quite nicely and aggressively but I'm using Windows 7 64bit OS (programming for 32bit). I've seen other people online with the exact same problem have asked the component developer directly and his ultimate response was that it would never work and left it at that.

CEF4Delphi:
This was the most promising! I was able to place this into a DLL and open the browser from another application. Everything worked fine. The only problem I have with this is that it requires changes in the program file (.dpr) which are fine in such a small POC, but will not be acceptable in the main program that this would ultimately be used with (the program file in question has nearly 2000 lines already).

Here are the required changes for CEF4Delphi
From:

```
    program Project1;

    uses
      Vcl.Forms,
      Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

    {$R *.res}

    begin
      Application.Initialize;
      Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
      Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
      Application.Run;
    end.
```

To:

```
    program Project1;

    uses
      Vcl.Forms,
      uCEFApplication,
      Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

    {$R *.res}

    {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}

    begin
      GlobalCEFApp := TCefApplication.Create;

      if GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess then
        begin
          Application.Initialize;
          Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
          Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
          Application.Run;
        end;

      GlobalCEFApp.Free;
     end.
```

The calling app is done in Delphi 2006, and I've tried using Delphi 2006 and also Delphi 10.2 for the DLLs. So I've had a least two versions of each DLL with no success apart from CEF4Delphi which won't be usable because the higher ups will never agree to the changes to the .dpr file.

I stumbled upon a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871348/program-hangs-when-unloading-a-dll-making-use-of-gdiplus) yesterday. I was intrigued by the answer from David Heffernan, specifically his conclusion about modifying the initialization and finalization sections of the components.

So I have two questions relating to DCEF3:

Would it be possible to edit the these sections of the components code to force fit it to work as a DLL?

If so, how would I go about it? I understand the obvious thing would be to "make it look" similar to the code suggested by David Heffernan in his response to the other question, but like I said, I'm relatively new to Delphi so really don't know how this particular code would look in this scenario.

Or if anyone else has any suggestions with the other two components I'm all ears. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know `CEF4Delphi` but I wonder what changes to the `.dpr` file are required?

Comment: There is more info on it here [CEF4Delphi](https://www.briskbard.com/index.php?lang=en&pageid=cef) Sorry I'm still getting used to the mini-Markdown formatting.

Comment: Sorry, if I ask for additional information to be able to answer your question, I expect a direct answer. I did however make an exception, and followed the link, and I saw nothing that would answer my request.

Comment: This question is far too broad and should be closed. If you are new to Delphi, and don't have much low level Windows programming experience, then this task may be too great. For instance, you can certainly use modern standards compliant IE with `TWebBrowser`. You just need to know the magic invocations. You've given up on that far too soon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what are these magic invocation? I have attempted to make changes to the registry settings, such as setting browser emulation to different modes and also reading through the documentation for other registry settings that also affect TWebBrowser. But my actual question is related to DCEF3, I only wanted to give some context for what I've tried so far by speaking about the other two components.

Comment: It can be done with `TWebBrowser`, from experience. Still, the question is way too broad. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok, so here is an example of a website that loads correctly in IE, but not in the TWebBrowser component with the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION set to Doc mode 11. [detectmybrowser.com](http://detectmybrowser.com/). The plugin check doesn't render properly in TWebBrowser for me. In IE it displays red dots for most of the plugins and version numbers for Silverlight and Flash. In TWebBrowser it just displays the plugin names with no red dots or version numbers. I've searched for a number of days trying to find out why, alas I haven't found any possible solution.

Comment: As well as that change it is usually worth setting the user agent string. For instance, I use this: `'Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393'` in my program. Set the user agent with `OleCheck(UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, PAnsiChar(UserAgent), Length(UserAgent) + 1, 0));`

Comment: But as you said, all of that is off to the side of the question you asked, which is still too broad

Comment: Aren't a lot of TWebBrowser issues solved by calling `OleInitialize(nil);` once on application start-up (e.g. FormCreate)?

Comment: CEF4DElphi now has a demo called DLLBrowser that is exactly what is described in the question. 

https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/tree/master/demos/DLLBrowser

That demo only needs the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag in the DPR file in case you need to load large images in the browser but you can ignore this flag if the images are small. It uses a different EXE for the browser subprocesses and it initializes and finalizes CEF with a couple of DLL functions.